# make the program work properly without the need to download a new gradle

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle

I get an Android project from git (clone) When I want to run it with android studio, it takes a lot of time to download the new gradle.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening and make the program work properly without the need to download a new gradle?

Comment: No, there is no way. If the files that gradle uses are not found, that's when the ide downloads the necessary to run the app, if that's not happening, how to do expect to compile?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the version of the gradle of this project to the gradle version that already you've on android-studio. To do that you can use a text editor to change:

1. In `myAppName\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` file, in the line `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip`: change to the gradle version you've (so you need to change this number in your example `6.7.1`)

You can know the gradle version you have from `C:/Users/myUserName/.gradle/wrapper/dists/`

2. In `myAppName\build.gradle` you need to change the gradle plugn version to be matched with the gradle distribution version you've from step no.1. [Documentation table that lists which version of Gradle is required for each version of the Android Gradle plugin.](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

**There is another way but it's tedious:**

1. First download the github project as a zip file, and extract it.
2. Create a new Android Studio Project.
3. Manually migrate files from the github project to the new project:

- Copy all the behavior, resources, assets and layout files from the original project to the brand new project.
- Copy all dependencies from `myAppName\app\build.gradle` into your project build.gradle (module level)
- Copy required class paths & repositories from `myAppName\build.gradle` into your project build.gradle (Project level)
- Copy data from the manifest file to the one of the new project.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar question, and found a solution to it, it might help

**Question**: I had created a library and wanted to update it with some fixes after quite some time. When trying to build project on new system after long, build failed due to issue related with Java version ultimately to gradle.

**Approach**: To try to use the default/original project without changing anything (it was working before, it should still work)

**Solution**: With the newer installation of Android Studio, I had upgraded version of gradle installed, with upgraded JDK version (17 in my case). I changed my project settings to use Gradle JDK version to JDK version 11.0.20 and that solved the problem. (Android Studio provided option to download JDK, I only needed to select the version (version: Flamingo 2022.2.1).
I used the project settings dialog to change the JDK version